# how to convert a tensor to a numpy array without enabling the run_eagerly flag in keras

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am writing my own metric call-back functions where I use sklearn to calculate the metrics and for that I need to have the y_true and y_pred tensors as numpy arrays. My functions look like this:

```
def precision_macro(y_true, y_pred):
    # get the y_true and y_pred tensors as 1-D numpy array
    y_true_array = np.array(true)
    y_pred_array = np.array(pred)
    ....................
    ....................
        CALCULATIONS
    ....................
    ....................
    precision = precision_score(y_true_array, y_pred_array, average="macro", zero_division=0)
    return precision
```

Everything works fine if I set the `run_eargly=True` during the compile call like this:

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr),
                      loss='binary_crossentropy',
                      metrics=model_metrics,
                      run_eagerly=True)
```

but this is very costly and way slower than with the flag set to False but if I don't set the flag to True I have a problem with the conversion. Here are things I have tried without setting the run_eagrly flag to True and didn't work:

If I just don't set the run_eagerly flag, I get the following error

> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (ExpandDims:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported

Then I tried

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def precision_macro(y_true, y_pred):
    # get the y_true and y_pred tensors as 1-D numpy array
    y_true_array = K.eval(y_true)
    y_pred_array = K.eval(y_pred)
    ....................
```

Or I try to call the numpy function on the tensors

```
def precision_macro(y_true, y_pred):
    # get the y_true and y_pred tensors as 1-D numpy array
    y_true_array = y_true.numpy()
    y_pred_array = y_pred.numpy()
    ....................
```

I also tried run this inside a session like this:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

def precision_macro(y_true, y_pred):
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    # get the y_true and y_pred tensors as 1-D numpy array
    with sess.as_default():
       y_true_array = K.eval(y_true)
       y_pred_array = K.eval(y_pred)
    ....................
```

I get the following error for all thress cases

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

I tried to run it like this:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

def precision_macro(y_true, y_pred):
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    # get the y_true and y_pred tensors as 1-D numpy array
    with sess.as_default():
       y_true_array = sess.run(y_true)
       y_pred_array = sess.run(y_pred)
    ....................
```

I get the following error

> InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
> (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'iterator' with dtype resource
> (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'iterator' with dtype resource

I tried downgrading numpy from `1.19.5` to `1.18.5` but that didn't work either, I get the same errors

trying `tf.numpy_function()`

```
import tensorflow as tf

def numpy_function(y_true, y_pred):
    # get the y_true and y_pred tensors as 1-D numpy array
    y_true_array = y_true
    y_pred_array = y_pred
    .... calculations ....
    precision = precision_score(y_true_array, y_pred_array, average="macro", zero_division=0)
    precision_per_class.append(precision_score(y_true_array, y_pred_array, average=None, zero_division=0))
    return precision
```

the function I pass as metric

```
@tf.function
def precision_macro(y_true, y_pred):
    score = tf.numpy_function(numpy_function, [y_true, y_pred], tf.float32)

    return score
```

and I compile like this, where `model_metrics = ['accuracy', precision_macro]`

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=lr),
                      loss='binary_crossentropy',
                      metrics=model_metrics)
```

I get the following error

> TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

I am using `keras = 2.6.` `tensorflow = 2.6` `numpy = 1.19.5`

So, can anybody help me ?

Comment: I also tried to enable the eager execution before I convert the tenosr to numpy array and then disable it for the rest of the execution by calling tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() and tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution() and it doesn't work and if I print tf.executing_eagerly() directly after the enable it still prints False!

Answer (score 0):

You could try `tf.numpy_function`. It receives a function as argument and will automatically convert tensors to numpy arrays before passing into the function and convert the outputs of the function back to tensors. See example:

```
def my_numpy_func(y_true, y_pred):
  # y_true and y_pred are already numpy arrays
  # put all numpy or sklearn codes here
  return metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)

@tf.function
def custom_metric(y_true, y_pred):
  # y_true and y_pred are tensors
  # no numpy or sklearn code is allowed here
  score = tf.numpy_function(my_numpy_func, [y_true, y_pred], tf.float32)
  return score
```

It will allow you to have `run_eagerly = False` and in theory, run faster as most computations except this custom metric work in graph mode.

Comment: I disabled the run_eagerly and tried that. I got this error
>TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

I added a breakpoint() call in my_numpy_func and the arguments are still being passed as Tensors!

Comment: If I enable the run_eagerly the arguments are passed as numpy arrays. So maybe the question is can I enable the flag only for the metric calculation ?

Comment: Please make sure all the `tf.compat.v1.X` or tensorflow v1 codes are removed first (and don't try those codes again) as those codes are buggy and break things in tensorflow v2. Then, please also post the codes of the metric, i.e. `precision_macro` and `my_numpy_func` when you tried `tf.numpy_function` including showing how you called `model.compile`.

Comment: For example, one way I could reproduce your error was doing `model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='sgd',metrics=[my_numpy_func])`, instead you should call `model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='sgd',metrics=[custom_metric])` for it to work.

Comment: can you please check the last part of the question, I modified it and I use nothing from ```tf.compat.v1```

Comment: when I run eagerly the arguments are passed as numpy arrays correctly

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you described by the limited information you provided. If you want help from others or if you found something unexpected that seems like a bug, please provide minimal standalone example of codes that can reproduce the problem. Regarding your question, using `tf.numpy_function` is the solution that requires minimal (almost zero) effort. There are also other solutions but involve much more codes writing.